# Saying "I do X so that I am able to do Y"

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to say "I do X so that I can do Y".

For example: "I work so that I can enjoy life".

The closest I've been able to get is something like:

働【はたら】くから、人生【じんせい】を楽【たの】しめます。
(*because* I work, I can enjoy life)

Is there a way of saying this with a closer implication to the original English?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

働くから人生を楽しめます ("I can enjoy life because I work"; 働**う** should be a typo for 働**く**) makes sense, but there is some difference in meaning.

To describe your purpose ("in order to", "so that", ...), you can use ～ように or ～ために. For the difference, see:  [On the interchangeability of ~ように and ~ために](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36593/5010)

> - 人生を楽しむために働きます。
> - 人生を楽しめるように働きます。

Reference:

- [Japanese Grammar on Expressing Benefit & Purpose](http://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/japanese-grammar-tame.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot @naruto, this is a great answer and exactly what I needed.