# Which ように is it 落ち着かせるように?

Tags: grammar, meaning

In the sentence below, I am not sure whether it is saying "so as to calm me down" or "as if to calm me down". I could imagine 落ち着かせるように being used to mean either of these meanings, so I am not sure how to distinguish between the two.

> そんな私を**落ち着かせるように**、肩に手を置いてポンポンと叩いてきてくれる

Comment: Gonna need a bit more context (source text, surrounding text, etc.) but I'm assuming it's the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> そんな私を落ち着かせる**ように**、肩に手を置いてポンポンと叩いてきてくれる

The ように means "as if".

To say "so that~" here, you'd say:

> そんな私を落ち着かせる**ために**、肩に手を置いてポンポンと叩いてきてくれる

To use the ように in the sense of "so that~" here, you'd need to say:

> そんな私**が落ち着く**ように、肩に手を置いてポンポンと叩いてきてくれる

Related:

- [On the interchangeability of ~ように and ~ために](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36593/9831)
   <sub>To mean "so that~" you'd say 学生が勉強する**ように**、先生は毎日宿題を出します rather than 学生が勉強するために～. 学生に勉強**させるために**毎日先生は宿題を出します sounds good but 学生に勉強**させるように**毎日先生は宿題を出します sounds off.</sub>
- [Difference between ために and ように](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12450/9831)
  <sub>`ように is used when you cannot control the situation ("so that").`</sub>

Answer (score 1):

= So that I calm down, so as to calm me down, (in order) to calm me down.
*"(They) put their hand on my shoulder and patted me (so as) to calm me down."*

If you wanted to include the pointed implication that it's for show or is futile in "as if to calm me down", you can add か to make "落ち着かせるかのように".